# How does Zotero find the information used to rename PDFs, and how can one incorporate this functionality into a shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, pdf, rename, zotero

The bibliography management software Zotero can automatically rename manuscript PDFs in a `AUTHOR - YEAR - TITLE.pdf` format. [Per this question](https://superuser.com/q/542078/603560), Zotero doesn't support batch-renaming all PDFs in a directory or tree in-place. You have to drag small groups into the GUI and do it bit by bit. This is not good.

I'd like to incorporate the PDF renaming functionality into shell scripts and other software. I've attempted to re-implement this using the Python library `pdf2doi` along with API calls to `crossref.org` to get bibliography information from DOIs. Sadly, the PDF information and DOIs it retrieved have a far higher error rate than Zotero.

Does anyone know where in the Zotero codebase the pull-bibliography-details-and-rename-PDF functionality is implemented, and whether it is possible to extract this in a self-contained application or script that can be called by other programs or incorporated into them?